# Why iOS 12 saving user-name instead of email to Keychain in completion of registration process?

Tags: user-interface, keychain, ios12

On iOS 12, when a user signs up and saves their password, Keychain saves the username and password.
Is it possible to instead save the email address and password, as these are the credentials needed when logging in?
In the previous version of ios its works fine.
I already try to set the text-field-content-type with "email address" and also with "username".

Answer (score 0):

After investing 4 to 5 hours, I found the solution to this problem. Actually, the problem was related to the order of its input text fields. Well as I already mentioned that earlier the content type and order was -

[image: Problem snapshot]
          Email textfiled      as "username" 
          UserName textfield   as "name"
          Password textfield   as "password"
Please have a look at this previous image -

which was producing an error as it was saving "Password" textfields's value in the keychain for Password but for Email it was saving "UserName" textfield's values in keychain in place of "Email" textfiled's value. Now to resolve this problem I have to change its order (content type will be same as previous one) as  -

```
      UserName textfield as "name"
      Email textfiled    as "username" 
      Password textfield as "password"
```

So after this little change, it saves in keychain "Email" textfields's value in "Email" which was actually required.

Now, this is the snapshot of updated one -

[image: soluation snapshot]